# How do I use GWT Widget.fireEvent?

Tags: gwt

I want to make a child widget fire an event and its parent to react to it. As far as I understand that is what `Widget.fireEvent` is for. But the following code does not work:

```
public class EntryPointClass implements EntryPoint {
private final HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
public void onModuleLoad() {
    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    verticalPanel.add(horizontalPanel);
    horizontalPanel.setHeight("500px");
    horizontalPanel.setWidth("500px");
    horizontalPanel.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
            log("onClick");
            horizontalPanel.fireEvent(new ChangeEvent() {
            });
        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
    verticalPanel.addDomHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            log("onChange");
        }
    }, ChangeEvent.getType());
    RootPanel.get().add(verticalPanel);
}

private static native void log(String msg) /*-{
    $wnd.console.log(msg);
}-*/;
```

}

`onClick` gets printed but `onChange` does not. What am I doing wrong? Or do I get the purpose of `Widget.fireEvent` wrong?

Comment: I think you should consider using EventBus. It's class dedicated for being a proxy between sender and receiver. Bear in mind, that sending events is quite expensive operation. In such situation as above I would just refer to Panel references instead of sending of events between them.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChangeEvent` is a DOM event, indicating that a [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event was fired by the browser from one of the dom elements in that widget.

The class is not meant to have instances created other than by GWT's internal browser event wiring, which is why in your code you need to make a subclass of it in order to even make an instance. Firing an event of this type doesn't actually cause the elements to change, so I'm not exactly sure what you have in mind by doing this here.

Consider instead using the logical event `ValueChangeEvent<T>` to indicate that a value has changed in a widget, though to be used correctly, the firing widget should implement `HasValueChangeHandlers<T>`.

---

Finally, you fired the event from your `horizontalPanel` instance, but are listening from the `verticalPanel`, so you aren't going to see this go off. While browser events are bubbled up within the dom elements (until something calls `stopPropagation()` on them), you aren't actually firing a dom event on an element, but are firing the wrapped class off of the widget, so no bubbling will occur.

Comment: But if there is no bubbling what is the point of firing events from widgets and not to an event bus?

Comment: Bubbling makes good sense for dom elements, where the browser doesn't know the logical breakdown (i.e. where one widget stops and another starts), but Widgets by definition _are_ that breakdown. Using an eventbus for app-wide communication makes more sense if you want to broadcast events, than listening for 'global' events by adding handlers to the `<body>` tag.